# Very long execution time for sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance

I have trying to execute the following sql query with good response time, but when I add the ORDER BY statement the query doesn't return anything for more than 5 min.

```
SELECT *  
FROM orders co
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM prod_orders) AS pc
ON co.id_order = pc.id_order
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM clients) AS cl
ON co.id_client = cl.id_client
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM clients_address) AS ca
ON co.id_client = ca.id_client
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM clienti_firme) AS cf
ON ca.id_client = cf.id_client
ORDER BY co.id_order
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`.

Comment: Will in not work without all of the inner Select * statements, i.e. left join clients as c1.  I'd imagine they are making a big difference to performance

Comment: @user2989408 not particular reason, but it's happening the same

Comment: If you have no reason to use `OUTER JOINS` then don't use them. You do not even have a filter condition. No wonder the performance is not good.

Comment: You should also limit the columns instead of * for every query.

Comment: @RickS I will try this, but there are like 20 columns

Comment: Do you absolutely need to return ALL the columns from EVERY table?

Comment: To see if the payload of all of the columns being returned is the issue run the query with this as the select clause: 

SELECT co.id_order

If it runs quick then returning all of the column from all of the tables is the slowdown.

Comment: @RickS Of course, I don't need all of them, but I just tried with only 2 columns, and the results are identical. Maybe that is not the problem.

Comment: What database is this?

Comment: @sean Tried and no luck; I use SELECT co.id_order and nothing changed

Comment: You need to make sure your tables are indexed properly.  And use sean's suggestion of changing your query.

Comment: @RickS Sorry to ask, but how to check if tables are properly indexed?

Comment: First, i would like to know how many rows returned when you take out the order by.

Comment: @RickS After I changed LEFT JOIN with JOIN and SELECT * with SELECT co.id_order the query returned 51578 rows

Comment: If you don't know if you've indexed the tables, then chances are you haven't.  http://use-the-index-luke.com/ is an excellent tutorial on indexing.

Comment: Please post indexes for your tables and the explain plan for your query. Without them you'll only get a guess, which isn't of much use to you. It's better to get the best possible answer.

Comment: @all I resolved this by adding all necessary columns to be indexed by sql. The problem was that not all columns with id_* has been indexed. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

If the Order By is slowing it down try:

```
SELECT *  
FROM (SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY id_order) AS co
LEFT JOIN prod_orders AS pc
ON co.id_order = pc.id_order
LEFT JOIN clients AS cl
ON co.id_client = cl.id_client
LEFT JOIN clients_address AS ca
ON co.id_client = ca.id_client
LEFT JOIN clienti_firme AS cf
ON ca.id_client = cf.id_client
ORDER BY co.id_order
```

Maybe the execution plan of all of the derived tables is making it run SELECT * for each row of the first table (orders). Try this instead:

```
SELECT *  
FROM orders co
LEFT JOIN prod_orders AS pc
ON co.id_order = pc.id_order
LEFT JOIN clients AS cl
ON co.id_client = cl.id_client
LEFT JOIN clients_address AS ca
ON co.id_client = ca.id_client
LEFT JOIN clienti_firme AS cf
ON ca.id_client = cf.id_client
ORDER BY co.id_order
```

Comment: I just tried and the results are the same; without ORDER BY statement works OK, but with it ... just "hangs"

Comment: Do you have indexes on these tables?  Also, how many rows are returned ?

Comment: Good suggestion Rick. Could add indexes to:

Prod_orders.id_order
clients.id_client
clients_address.id_client
clienti_firme.id_client

Comment: Sorry, just understood that the ORDER BY is slowing it down. Is orders.id_order the primary key?

Comment: @sean yes is primary key for orders table

Comment: I think your running into innoDB's issues with late lookups. I will post one more query to try. I would change your question to include "with order by" and add the mysql tag. Hopefully someone with more mysql experience can help.

Answer (score 0):

The query provided by Sean is about as simple as it would get... That said, I would ensure you have the following indexes on all respective tables

```
prod_orders ( id_order )
clients ( id_client )
clients_address ( id_client )
clienti_firme (id_client)

and of course your 
orders ( id_order )
```

The only ADDITIONAL thing I would since you mentioned MySQL.  try adding the keyword "STRAIGHT_JOIN"... I don't think it would make a difference since all your tables are LEFT-JOINs, but you never know.

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN ... rest of query ...
```

The only other thing I can think of that may be killing it is some sort of Cartesian result of data.  yes, an order should be associated with a single client, but if that client has multiple addresses (home, work, alternate office, etc  and we don't know your table relationships), and again for clienti_firme (multiple records the client is associated with), you could be blowing through more than you expect.

If you have 100 orders for a single client, and that client has 3 addresses and is associated with 10 firms, you now have 100 * 3 * 10 records coming through where you may have originally expected only 100 (now getting 3000).  Do that with all the orders, clients, etc and you see how it COULD become a problem.